# Oracle - Erro ao conectar com ADOConnection Delphi 10.1 (Berlin)

Tags: delphi, oracle, odbc, delphi-10

Tenho uma aplicação que funciona em *Delphi XE2* utilizando o componente de conexão a banco de dados *ADOConnection*. Quando migrei para o *Delphi 10.1 (Berlin)*, não apresentou nenhum erro. A conexão existe, porem não conecta, e apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A string de conexão e essa:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=gestor02;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=gestor02;Data Source=192.168.1.3:1521/des;Extended Properties=""
```

O drive OraOLEDB.Oracle aparece nos 2 delphis:

**DELPHI XE2:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**DELPHI 10.1(Berlin):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A mensagem de erro acontece quando clico no botão `Avançar>>>`

No *Delphi XE2* não da erro, o erro só acontece no *Delphi 10.1*. 
Ja reinstalei o cliente do *Oracle*, mas ainda continua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema instalando o Delphi 10 (Seatle), nele funcionou sem problemas. Como a minha necessidades era migrar para uma versão mais atual para utilizar algumas funções do FastReport que no exemplo que eu vi era no Delphi Seatle, então pra mim resolveu.